# BigQuery Transfer stuck in Pending State

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, transfer

Am I the only one who is facing this???

[image]

Bigquery transfer is stuck in Pending state. When the trigger times come it extend the scheduled time. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to analyze some [logs or monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/working-with-transfers#logging_and_monitoring)?

Answer (score 0):

I think that just means there aren't free sources available in GCP to run your job yet. There's nothing you can do apart from waiting I think!